# Proving that $2444_b$ is not a perfect square in any base $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Here's the question:

> Prove that there is no (positive integer) base $b$
> such that $2444_b$ is a perfect square

**My attempt**:

Suppose, if possible, $2444_b$ is a perfect square in some base $b$.

**Case 1**: $3\nmid b$

By Fermat's little theorem:

$\begin{align}2444_b&=2b^3+4(b^2+b+1) \\&\equiv 2b+1(1+b+1)\\ &\equiv 2 \pmod 3\end{align}$

A perfect square $\text{mod } 3$ cannot be $2$. (Contradiction)

**Case 2**: $3\mid b$

Clearly, $b$ must be even because:

$2\mid 2444_b\implies 4\mid 2444_b\implies 2\mid b^3$

Thus, $6\mid b$.

I can't find a contradiction in this case.

According to WolframAlpha, the only integer solutions of $2x^3+4(x^2+x+1)=y^2$ are $(0,\pm 2)$.

Comment: @OlderAmateur Every digit is even. $2\mid (2b^3+4b^2+4b+4)$

Comment: @OlderAmateur Since $2444_b$ is perfect square and $2$ divides $2444_b$, we need $4\mid 2444_b$.  Now, $$4\mid (2b^3+4b^2+4b+4)\\ \implies 4\mid 2b^3\\ \implies 2\mid b^3\\ \implies 2\mid b$$

Comment: @OlderAmateur I don't understand what you mean. Did you  mean $\text{gcd}(\sqrt{2444_b},b)=1$ if $b\neq 2^1$? If so, why?

Comment: @OlderAmateur Why can't the gcd be any other multiple of 2? BTW, use \sqrt{2444} if you want to cover the entire thing under square root.

Comment: @OlderAmateur Nice observation $2440_b\equiv 4\pmod{8}$...

Comment: Im assuming you mean $2444_b$

Comment: @OlderAmateur yes.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are integers such that
$$2b^3+4b^2+4b+4=a^2.\tag{1}$$
Set $x=2b+1$ and $y=2a$ to get the minimal Weierstrass form
$$y^2=x^3+x^2+3x+11,$$
which is an elliptic curve with integral points $(x,y)=(-2,\pm1)$ and $(x,y)=(1,\pm4)$, see [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/352/d/1). Only the latter pair correspond to integral solutions to $(1)$, but with $b=0$ which is not a sensible base.